# ValueList from ExecuteSQL() based query in FMP 12

Tags: filemaker

I'm looking into upgrading our FMP11 developed solution to FMP12. For us, key functionality exists around the ValueList feature to DISPLAY one value (e.g. a description) while RETURNING another value (e.g. a UID), into the selected field.

I would be interested if you have been able to replicate this feature from the ExecuteSQL() function (I can successfully return a single ValueList ... having trouble with the above)

many thanks in advance
Giles

Answer (score 2):

Based on the core functionality of value lists, you can't use the `ExecuteSQL()` function to calculate the value directly inside of the value list dialog box.

What you would have to do is create a table with a single record and two fields. Then you would use an `ExecuteSQL()` calculation to populate the first and second fields with data. It would be important to make sure you sort your data inside `executeSQL()` in the same order in both fields.

So your filemaker calculations would be (assuming the first field is `key` and the second is `name` and it's from a table called items, and you are looking for where `key > 100`)

```
keylist = 
ExecuteSQL ( 
"SELECT key 
FROM items 
WHERE key > 100
ORDER BY key ASC"
; "" ; "" )

namelist = 
ExecuteSQL ( 
"SELECT name 
FROM items 
WHERE key > 100
ORDER BY key ASC"
; "" ; "" )
```

You would then create a value list that uses keylist as the first field, and namelist as the second field, only displaying values from the second field.

It would be nice to have the functionality to calculate a value list, but as far as I know filemaker always needs to pull values from a source outside of the value list dialog box.